# Elastic search - copying indexes with data from one linux server to another

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 4 indexes with 10GB data in my dev Linux (CentOS) machine, I want to copy these 4 indexes from dev to prod server (CentOS). Can some one suggest the easy and robust approach, meaning all the dev indexes get copied over to prod server and indexes created on prod server automatically as per the index mapping in the dev server. I tried snapshot and Restore API this didn't work.

Comment: Well `snapshot` and `restore` is the best option in your case, in my opinion. Maybe you should try to explain why it did not work.